# Why am I getting this error: "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option" after running a PL/SQL procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created a table Patient with some attributes, like p_name, p_surname, p_number... I would like to create a procedure to transfer a patient from this table Patient to another table (Patient_backup), case his "p_number" attribute has received an input, deleting it from the first table and remaining only in the second. The second table has the same structure of the first one. I have coded the procedure like that.

```
CREATE TABLE patient (
p_number      VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
p_name            VARCHAR2(15),
p_surname         VARCHAR2(15),
p_street            VARCHAR2(20),
p_city            VARCHAR2(15)
);

CREATE TABLE patient_backup (
p_number      VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
p_name            VARCHAR2(15),
p_surname         VARCHAR2(15),
p_street            VARCHAR2(20),
p_city            VARCHAR2(15)
);

CREATE [OR REPLACE] PROCEDURE transfer (p_number VARCHAR2)
AS
CURSOR k1 IS SELECT p_number FROM patient;
BEGIN
OPEN k1;
LOOP
FETCH k1 INTO p_number;
IF p_number IS NULL THEN
dbms_output.put_line('empty');
ELSE
INSERT INTO patient_backup (SELECT * FROM patient);
Execute Immediate 'Drop Table patient;';
END IF;
END LOOP;
CLOSE k1;
END transfer;
```

But when I run it,I get the error "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option". Could you help me with that? I wonder if the code is correct. I have read a material about PL/SQL, but the concepts were not connected to each other, so I just tried to gather everything together, and I hope it is correct. Could you help me to correct this code and make it work?

Comment: The procedure doesn't compile for me in 12.2. The error is *PLS-00403: expression 'P_NUMBER' cannot be used as an INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement.*  This is because IN parameters are read-only, so you can't fetch anything into it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to tell where exactly the error is, but my guess is: remove the `;` from inside the string for `execute immediate`.

But I think you want do **not** want to `DROP` the table - that removes the table completely from the database including **all** rows and its definition. It won't be accessible after that.

I *think* what you really want is to `DELETE` a row from that table, not remove the table completely.

Also: the whole loop is completely unnecessary (and inefficient).  You can do that with two simple SQL statements:

```
insert into patient_backup
select *
from patient
where p_number = 42; --<< to pick one patient

delete from patient 
where p_number = 42;
```

Putting that into a procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE transfer (p_number_to_delete VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
  insert into patient_backup
  select *
  from patient
  where p_number = p_number_to_delete;

  delete from patient 
  where p_number = p_number_to_delete;

END transfer;
```

It's highly recommended to not use the name of a column as the name of a parameter. That's why I named the parameter `p_number_to_delete` (but `p_number` is a bad name for a column that isn't a number to begin with - but that's a different discussion)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `DECLARE` your cursor before you define it.

Comment: This `CURSOR k1 IS SELECT p_number FROM patient;` **is** a cursor declaration, isn't it? If you meant to say that the procedure needs the `declare` keyword, you're wrong. Anonymous PL/SQL blocks do, but stored procedures don't - it is invalid in that context.

Comment: Thank you, very interesting.  I had always done ```DECLARE``` in front of variables in stored procedures.  In doing this I would have to put a ```BEGIN``` before the declaration, which then results in having extra ```END```s and the end.  I just tested and confirmed, the ```DECLARE``` is not needed as long as variables are defined before any ```BEGIN``` is issues.

Comment: You're welcome; now you can save some space by omitting that unnecessary inner BEGIN-END block :)

Comment: Yeap.  I always thought it was weird that I would end up with multiple ```END;``` statements that then end of SPs.  This is definitely one reason why..

Answer (score 0):

**In Your procedure code have some error**

1.P_NUMBER input parameter cannot be used into statment
 2.don't use semicolon inside the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE string
 3. in loop statement you should use exit otherwise it will run
    continuously

**Here the code**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TRANSFER (P_NUMBER IN VARCHAR2) AS
CURSOR K1 IS 
    SELECT P_NUMBER FROM PATIENT;
P_NUM PLS_INTEGER;    
BEGIN
    OPEN K1;
        LOOP
            FETCH K1 INTO P_NUM;
                IF P_NUM IS NULL THEN
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPTY');
                ELSE
                    INSERT INTO PATIENT_BACKUP (SELECT * FROM PATIENT);
                    DELETE FROM PATIENT;
                END IF;
                EXIT WHEN P_NUM IS NULL;
        END LOOP;
CLOSE K1;
END TRANSFER;
```